# MYSQL navigation bar adding category to categories table but check if category already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I made a navigation bar where I store my menus on my webpage.

I created a table for it called `categories`, and I managed to add a category to it via a button. I can add everything to it, but if I add something to it, I want to check if it already exists in the `categories` table. If it does, then echo 'already exists`. If not, insert the data.

I can't solve this. Thanks for the help.

```
<?php

function addCategory(){
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          global $connection;
          $cat_title = $_POST['cat_title']; 

          if($cat_title == "" || empty($cat_title)){
              echo "this cannot be blank";
          } else {                            
              $query="INSERT INTO categories(cat_title)";// ADD CATEGORIES IN CATEGORIES.PHP //
              $query .= "VALUES ('$cat_title')";
              $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

              if(!$result){
                 die('Query failed' . mysqli_error);
              }

          }  
     }
} 

?>
```

Comment: The easiest way is just to create a SELECT statement before you do the insert. Another option is to create a unique index on `cat_title` and check for an inserted id after your query. A unique index will prevent any duplicates.

Comment: my friend said the same but i need instrunctions. is it possible to write it down? ( the two method ) i would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cat_title_index ON categories (cat_title)

This made my problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it has a couple of steps. One changes the database itself to enforce a rule that the `cat_title` column in your `categories` table never has a duplicate.

The documentation for the first step is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html), but it takes a lot of practice to read that stuff. It's worth getting used to it, though, if you plan on using MySQL for any amount of time.

For you, the statement is probably as simple as:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cat_title_index ON categories (cat_title)
```

You run that command ONCE, and it permanently modifies your database. You might have a visual database admin tool that you can use to accomplish the same thing.

Once that's done, you will never have two categories with the same title (and searching by title will be faster).

Then, when you execute your code above, how do you know if an insert was done?

It turns out that's pretty easy, too. php has [a way to check what was inserted](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) - if the answer is zero, then nothing was:

```
$insertId = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
if ($insertId === 0) {
    // return "already have that category" message
}
```

Put this after you run your insert statement and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. i tried to run the command on phpmyadmin SQL menu. and it says.

The MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicated entry '' as the 'cat_title_index'  key.

Comment: That might mean you already have a duplicate cat_title. If so, you'll have to clean up the data before you can run that line. If you create the index using phpmyadmin's GUI you might get a more informative error message. I haven't used phpmyadmin in years, so I can't tell you specifically how to do that.

Comment: I marked your answer as solved :) thanks for the help i had to delete the duplicated items from the table now it works :) i cant insert the same data anymore thats good :) but when i try to write the same it says an error how can i solve that to write something else like "you are trying to enter something already exists"  instead of the error?

Comment: if there is an error, try calling `mysqli_error()` and `mysqli_errno()` to see what the code is for duplicate entry. (it's probably 1062, like you saw above). You can check for that code and return the message. I'll edit my answer to reflect that after I check a little more.

Comment: Modified to show how to return different messages for different "errors".

Comment: thanks :) there wasn't anymore 1063 problem actually i had an error because your code was working and i had to do something to not to get the syntax on my page if i tried to insert same value to check your code is working :)  and sorry for disturbing you

Answer (score 0):

you should consider making cat_title UNIQUE in the data base and then catch the resulted sql exception

or:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT cat_title FROM 
 categories WHERE category =" +$cat_title);
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
     // insert the new category
} else {
    echo "category exists ";
}
```

you can further refine the query by using 'like' instead of equal  to includ misspelled inserted categories and show the user the category name to deside to insert or not.
a better design is to make a function1($cat_title) to check for exact equality and return a boolean and a second function2($cat_title) to check with 'like %c%'  that returns a string or null sinse the returned value can be used as boolean in PHP if statment and a thired function3($cat_title) to insert and then simply call the 3 functions respectively in a (if ... else if... else) fashion and refine it in the else block to ask the user 
note that you can call function 1 and 2 as the if and else if conditions and call the insertion function inside the else block and inside the if else block in the midle you would prompt the user to insert or not and make an end point to insert the value.

sent from a mobile device by a none native english speaker ...please reformat

Comment: This will create a potential race condition - it's possible that the category can be added by another user between the check and the insert. That's REALLY unlikely, and for most sites probably not a concern, but it's worth considering.